# Unwanted behavior with CMake+Ninja+Emacs

Tags: cmake, fortran, ninja

I am writing a Fortran code using Emacs and CMake with the Ninja generator. If, instead of Ninja I use `make` as the generator, and there's a coding mistake, I get an error message like

```
/home/raul/Projects/test/main.f90:54:9:

   my_cols = 1
     1
Error: Symbol ‘my_cols’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

Emacs reports the correct location of the source file along with line and column numbers so that I can quickly jump to the offending code. On the other hand, with Ninja, the error message returned looks something like this:

```
CMakeFiles/run.dir/main.f90-pp.f90:54:9:


         1
Error: Symbol ‘my_cols’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

I am pointed to what looks like a preprocessed Fortran source file, not the original source file. The line and column numbers correspond to the original file, and the contents of the error message is slightly different (the line above "1" has gone missing). This is clearly annoying because I need to make any fixes in the original file, not the preprocessed one. Is there any way to change this behavior? I'm not sure whether this has something to do with Emacs, Ninja, Cmake, or Fortran.

**EDIT.** Minimal example.

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(test Fortran)
add_executable(main main.f90)

# main.f90
  implicit none
  a = 5
end program
```

With gfortran, I get

```
[3/4] Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.f90.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.f90.o 
/usr/bin/f95  -I../  -c CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.f90-pp.f90 -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.f90.o
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.f90-pp.f90:2:3:

 # 1 "<built-in>"
   1
Error: Symbol ‘a’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Interestingly, with the Intel Fortran compiler (ifort) I get

```
[3/4] Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.f90.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.f90.o 
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/bin/intel64/ifort  -I../  -c CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.f90-pp.f90 -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.f90.o
../main.f90(2): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [A]
  a = 5
--^
compilation aborted for CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.f90-pp.f90 (code 1)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

The error message is slightly different and now it is able to point to the correct location. (On a more complex project with several subdirectories also ifort gets it wrong.)

Comment: It would help if you could provide a minimal example.  My gut says it's a ninja/cmake problem, because it's fine with make.  But you could probably fix it in Emacs because `compile` is just using regexps to find the file+line where the error is.

Comment: I think the thing to customize is `compilation-error-regexp-alist`.

Comment: I see that at the top of the preprocessed file there is the full path to the original source file. Maybe I can incorporate that into the regexp somehow. In any case, my guess is that CMake+Ninja+Fortran is not mature yet. This issue is probably not present with other languages because I haven't seen any complaints.

Comment: Yeah, with Ninja 1.7.2 (latest) and CMake 3.9.2 (git), cmake gives an error about ninja not supporting fortran, and that you need to rebuild ninja with a patch (which I assume you've done).  I'd say that's a good sign that it's not quite ready yet.  That said, you can still try to get compile to parse the filename differently.  I've never mucked around with that stuff, so I can't help much more.

Comment: Note: the issue is probably with CMake because I seem to be getting the correct with the meson build system.

Comment: Appearently, this issue can be traced to the peculiar behavior of gfortran (see https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17160). Strictly speaking, it's not a gfortran bug.